# Binding on-change in ClojureScript/Reagent

Tags: onchange, clojurescript, reagent, dplyr

I am trying to understand how input fields work in Reagent.

I first tried to bind `on-change` to a simple function that changes underlying atom:

```
(defonce app-state
  (reagent/atom "Teodor"))

(defn page [ratom]
  [:div
    [:p
      "Please enter your name: "
      [:input {:on-change #(swap! ratom %)
               :value @ratom}]]
    [:p "Your name is " @ratom]])
```

... which did not work. This, however, does:

```
(defonce app-state
  (reagent/atom "Teodor"))

(defn page [ratom]
  [:div
    [:p
      "Please enter your name: "
      [:input {;:on-change #(swap! ratom %)
               :on-change (fn [evt]
                             (reset! ratom (-> evt .-target .-value)))
               :value @ratom}]]
    [:p "Your name is " @ratom]])
```

I've managed to desugar the `->` macro:

```
(fn [evt]
  (reset! ratom (-> evt .-target .-value)))
;; is the same as
(fn [evt]
  (reset!
    ratom
    (.-value (.-target evt))))
```

1. What do `.-value` and `.-target` do?
2. Where can I find documentation for `.-value` and `.-target`?
3. Why choose the more complicated semantics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `evt` that is coming into your function is a JavaScript event object. `.-target` and `.-value` are the JavaScript DOM properties that allow you to access the underlying value that the event is holding.

Here you are in the world of JavaScript interop, so you will have to go to JavaScript for the documentation.

As far as the complicated semantics of using the `->` macro or not: that's just handy for people who like to unpeel properties from left to right as they read. The `->` macro will be making your code look similar to the equivalent JavaScript code.

Comment: Ah, that's why I didn't find anything searching ClojureScript docs.

Any recommended source for JavaScript documentation? I found docs from Mozilla and W3Schools, but I'm missing code examples.

I'm not a web developer here, as you might have guessed!

Comment: I started with Github ClojureScript code and then used Google for particular JavaScript problems. If you can't work something out that way then ask at the ClojureScript Slack group or here at SO. Something to get a little more apprehensive about is CSS!